# Guava cast HashBasedTable to TreeBasedTable

Tags: guava, guava-table

I am looking to cast class com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable to com.google.common.collect.TreeBasedTable.

Casting does not work.

```
 class com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable cannot be cast to class com.google.common.collect.TreeBasedTable
```

Is there an efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different *implementations* for generic [`Table`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) and thus cannot just be cast (similarly to `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, which cannot be case one to another).

You can however copy contents of any table to a new one, in your case:

```
// Create sample HashBasedTable
Table<Integer, Integer, String> hashBasedTable = HashBasedTable.create();
hashBasedTable.put(1, 1, "eleven");
hashBasedTable.put(4, 2, "forty two");
hashBasedTable.put(2, 4, "twenty four");
hashBasedTable.put(1, 4, "fourteen");
  // {1={1=eleven, 4=fourteen}, 4={2=forty two}, 2={4=twenty four}}

// Create TreeBasedTable (with natural ordering, use `.create(Comparator, Comparator)` otherwise)
final TreeBasedTable<Comparable, Comparable, Object> treeBasedTable = TreeBasedTable.create();
treeBasedTable.putAll(hashBasedTable);
System.out.println(treeBasedTable);
  // {1={1=eleven, 4=fourteen}, 2={4=twenty four}, 4={2=forty two}}
```